# How to use class / id in li that is created by string query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: html code of searchable multi-selector dropdown]

```js
$('.dropdown-container')
 .on('click', '.dropdown-button', function() {
     $('.dropdown-list').toggle();
 })
 .on('input', '.dropdown-search', function() {
     var target = $(this);
     var search = target.val().toLowerCase();
    
     if (!search) {
            $('li').show();
            return false;
        }
    
     $('li').each(function() {
         var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var match = text.indexOf(search) > -1;
            $(this).toggle(match);
        });
 })
 .on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function() {
     var numChecked = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
     $('.quantity').text(numChecked || 'Any');
 });
// JSON of States for demo purposes
var usStates = [
    { name: 'ALABAMA', abbreviation: 'AL'},
    { name: 'ALASKA', abbreviation: 'AK'},
    { name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA', abbreviation: 'AS'}    
];
// <li> template
var stateTemplate = _.template(
    '<li>' +
     '<input name="<%= abbreviation %>" type="checkbox">' +
     '<label for="<%= abbreviation %>"><%= capName %></label>' +
    '</li>'
);
// Populate list with states
_.each(usStates, function(s) {
    s.capName = _.startCase(s.name.toLowerCase());
    $('ul').append(stateTemplate(s));
});
```

I am trying to create a searchable multi-selector drop-down menu. But When I run this js file it changes all the li in the HTML. How Can I specify that js to only one div? So it won't mess with rest of the li or ul. As shown in the pic below.

[image: Error]

Comment: or simply I want to add class or id to li that is created  in string .

Answer (score 0):

change your selector to:

```
$('.dropdown-container .dropdown-list ul').append(stateTemplate(s));
```

and for the li's as well

```
$('.dropdown-container .dropdown-list ul li').each(function() {//....
```